# cmake with vcpkg on macOS cannot find header files

Tags: c++, macos, lib, vcpkg

I installed vcpkg on macOS and I'm trying to build a simple library that depends on `fmt`, which I installed with vcpkg.

mylib.h

```
float add(float a, float b);
```

mylib.cpp

```
#include "mylib.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fmt/core.h>

float add(float a, float b)
{
    fmt::print("Hello MYLIB, world!\n");
    return (a + b);
}
```

CMakeLists.txt contents:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19.1)

project(MYLIB)

find_package(fmt REQUIRED)

add_library(mylib mylib.cpp)
```

Then

```
user@users-MacBook-Pro build % cmake -B . -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=~/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake -S ..              
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 12.0.0.12000032
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 12.0.0.12000032
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/user/mylib/build
user@users-MacBook-Pro build % make
Scanning dependencies of target mylib
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/mylib.cpp.o
/Users/user/mylib/mylib.cpp:5:10: fatal error: 'fmt/core.h' file not found
#include <fmt/core.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/mylib.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What am I missing?

I tried the same on Windows and it works fine. On Windows though we run `vcpkg integrate install` which does not exist on macOS. Is this related to the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the variable `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` incorrectly. `set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE ...` in CMakeLists.txt has no effect. The variable should be set on the command line, see the manuals [CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE.html), [Using vcpkg with CMake](https://vcpkg.io/en/getting-started.html)

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=~/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake
```

The file CMakeLists.txt is also wrong, `find_package(fmt REQUIRED)` is missing, that should download and install `fmt` by invoking `vcpkg install fmt` under the hood.

After all you should link your project with the lib

```
target_link_libraries(MYLIB PRIVATE fmt::fmt)
```

Comment: Why there's no error/warning indicating incorrect use of `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE `?

Comment: It is like a global var. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=... defines a global one, set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE ...) changes a value that does not affect on actions performed before that change.

Comment: After following your instructions I still have the same problem. Perhaps I should ask how to debug this issue?

Comment: Really the same issue? If so, please update the question with the actual cmake files and logs.

Comment: Updated. Anything else I can provide?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's necessary to

```
include_directories(~/vcpkg/installed/x64-osx/include)
```